# Double-nested serializers with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Is this possible with DRF using ModelSerializers? I'm mostly interested in seeing an example to reproduce if possible.

Here are my models:

```
class Grandparent(Model):
    g_name = CharField(max_length=10)
    parent = ForeignKey('Parent')

class Parent(Model):
    p_name = CharField(max_length=10)
    child = ForeignKey('Child')

class Child(Model):
    c_name = CharField(max_length=10)
```

Here are my serializers:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Child
        fields = ('id', 'c_name')

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    child = ChildSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        child_data = validated_data.pop('child')
        child, _ = models.Child.objects.get_or_create(**child_data)
        return models.Parent.objects.create(child=child, **validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Parent
        fields = ('id', 'p_name', 'child')

class GrandparentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent = ParentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Grandparent
        fields = ('id', 'g_name', 'parent')
```

Here is my grandparent view:

```
class GrandparentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Grandparent.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.GrandparentSerializer
```

Here is the error I get when I try to post to the Grandparent view:

> AttributeError at /grandparents/ 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: The code is currently inconsistent with the error. There's no stack trace. At the moment, since there's no create in GrandparentSerializer, DRF will complains about adding it or declaring it as read_only

Comment: Have you tried running it? I would have thought this is the case but I'm getting the list error.

Comment: I tried overriding the create method for grandparent and it doesn't even appear to be called before the exception is raised.

Comment: I've run that code and got the error where DRf complains about GrandparentSerializer create method or read only missing

Comment: What version of DRF are you using? I'm using 3.2.3.

Comment: 3.3.1 but I don't think that'll change the behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue we found was that is a bug in the form front-end provided by DRF. Nested serializer behaved correctly when called directly over HTTP.

Comment: I cam across one of your question on Stack Exchange "Will this data mining approach work? Is it a good idea?" Have you came up to any conclusion , I am also facing with the same question, Please Suggest me.